# Limit the number of categories shows on page

Tags: php

I have this portion of code where categories are loaded from txt file.

```
<?php                       
  foreach ($categories as $cat) {               
    if ($cat['word'] == false)                          
      continue;                                                             
?>
  <li>
     <a href="cats/"><?php echo $cat['name']?></a>
  </li>
<?php } ?>
```

The problem is that they are a lot because they are pulled from outside and populated dynamically in the file. Because of that I want to limit them to 15 but I'm unable to do it.

I've tried with `for` and `while`, like:

```
<?php                       
  foreach ($categories as $cat) {             
    if ($cat['word'] == false)                         
      continue;               
      for($cat['word'] = 0; $cat['word'] <=15; $cat['word']++){                                  
?>
  <li>
     <a href="cats/"><?php echo $cat['name']?></a>
  </li>
<?php } 
   }?>
```

And

```
<?php                       
  foreach ($categories as $cat) {             
    if ($cat['word'] == false)                         
      continue;               
      while($cat['word'] = 15;){                                  
?>
  <li>
     <a href="cats/"><?php echo $cat['name']?></a>
  </li>
<?php } 
   }?>
```

Both variants result in empty names.

Comment: Is `$categories` an array? Would you like to filter the collection for `$cat['word']` _before_ or _after_ limiting the set to 15?

Comment: `array_slice()` allows you to take a segment of an array. `array_chunk()` lets you split it into segments.

Comment: Are all the links meant to be the same `href` or should there be some information from each `$cat` in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you'd like to filter out the `$cat['word'] == false` entries **before** limiting the results to the first 15 (ie so you get up to 15 entries shown), try something like this...

```php
$filtered = array_filter($categories, function($cat) {
    return $cat['word']; // only include truthy "word" entries
});
foreach (array_slice($filtered, 0, 15) as $cat) : ?>
<li>
 <a href="cats/"><?= $cat['name'] ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. This way is working. What will happen if there is nothing in the array? Is it going to crash?

Comment: No, it just won't output any `<li>` tags. The same will happen if all `$cat['word']` entries are _falsy_

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Will the following work for you?

```
<?php $count = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($categories as $cat) :?>
  <?php if ($cat['word'] == false) continue; ?>
  <li>
      <a href="cats/"><?php echo $cat['name']?></a>
  </li>
  <?php if ($count >= 15) break; ?>
  <?php $count++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the snipped.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  

$counter = 0;

  foreach ($categories as $cat) {               
    if ($cat['word'] == false){                          
      continue;                
     } 

if($counter < 15) { 

echo '<li>
     <a href="cats/"><?php echo $cat['name']?></a>
  </li>'

$counter++;
 }} ?>
```

Can be refactored.

Comment: You cannot `<?php echo` within a string being `echo`-ed. You also have a string-quoting error around `'name`

Comment: You are right, I did not see the echo inside, also I didnt realise there is php code inside.